# Is DynamoDB a good choice for user sessions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm thinking of using DDB for session management of a website: user logs in, a session ID is saved in database and cookie, every request checks database for session ID from cookie. I'm still in the design phase.

To prevent the scenario where a session is created during login but the following request doesn't find that session due to eventual consistency, I think strong consistency is needed. However strong consistency is slower, and using it for every request seems like a significant latency overhead.

1. Is my concern valid?
2. Is eventual consistency enough for session management?
3. Is DDB unsuitable for sessions, and if so, what is a more suitable datastore?

Answer (score 2):

One of DynamoDBs usecases is as you've rightly identified as a session store.

Some languages (for example PHP) have a ready by session handler in the SDK, if there is not one for your language take a look at the implementation for PHP [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/b06e2c2d171f6a86c3d200a2ce1a3537ac1398f3/src/DynamoDb/SessionHandler.php).

Regarding consistency, either strongly consistent or using [transactional consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/). Additionally it might be worth adding an attribute to contain the lock status of your session, this would then prevent any session collisions.

You could also take a look at using [Redis](https://redis.io/) as a session handler, AWS do have a managed service with [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) which would provide this.

Comment: I don't have any latency requirements yet, but also don't want every request taking an additional few seconds due to using strong consistency. Would that happen?

Comment: Depending on your application it should not add much time. Generally when I have seen it implemented you add an attribute with a lock status setting this to true. You only then write to the DynamoDB at the termination. This would be 2 writes for the entire process, with a single read. :)

Comment: What do you mean by session collision? I'm thinking my sessions will be identified by randomly generated UUID, so no collisions. How would the lock work? I don't see what the 2 writes and 1 read are.

Comment: Depending on your application if you have any asynchronous requests you might have a collision from both trying to read and write at the same time, which can lead to ones overriding another, this is why locking sessions exist. The flow is 1 read for the session, 1 write to lock it, and then 1 write to add the latest session data once the task has completed.